# How can I override passwd's checks for good passwords?

Tags: password, passwd

I have an encrypted /home and just had to reinstall Ubuntu. Problem is, my /home partition is encrypted with my old password, which is short, and my new system has a new password on it. I could fix this by setting my old password on the new system, and but passwd won't allow me to change the password to something short. Is there a way to override passwd's checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the password as the root user for a specific user.....it might complain but allow you to do it.