# How to change password of user to very simple like 'w'?

Tags: passwd

It says at least 6 characters. I want to change to easy input.
How to change password of user to very simple like one character 'w' ?
Thanks

Comment: It should work if you use sudo. `sudo passwd $user`. Be warned , if you use sudo to change your password you will break encryption of your home directory if you are using encryption.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How can I override passwd's checks for good passwords?](http://askubuntu.com/q/237131/107450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `sudo passwd $USER` in a terminal, replace `$USER` with the username you want to set the password for.

`$USER` is the same as the current user if you don't want to type your own name.

Be warned , if you use sudo to change your password you will break encryption of your home directory if you are using encryption.